# I want to select a comment node based on attribute value

Tags: java, xml, xpath

XML NODE

```
 <!-- url path="/jsp/Admin_BetaSignup.jsp" roles="ZohoCampaignAdmin" authentication="optional" description="Page used to add the Beta users">
        <param name="zuid" xss="throwerror" max-len="300"/>
</url -->
```

I Want to select this node via xpath . I use below code in java .

```
Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
    .newDocumentBuilder()
    .parse("/home/local/ZOHOCORP/bharathi-1397/build/AdventNet/Sas/webapps/zcadmin/WEB-INF/security.xml");
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
System.out.println(
    xpath.evaluate("//comment()[@path='/jsp/Admin_BetaSignup.jsp']",
    document,XPathConstants.NODE)
);
```

Output : null .

Why?

Comment: I don't think comments can have attributes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//comment()[contains(., 'path="/jsp/Admin_BetaSignup.jsp"')]
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "//comment()
         [contains(., 'path=&quot;/jsp/Admin_BetaSignup.jsp&quot;')]
    "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the XML document below:**

```
<!-- url path="/jsp/Admin_BetaSignup.jsp" roles="ZohoCampaignAdmin" authentication="optional" description="Page used to add the Beta users">         <param name="zuid" xss="throwerror" max-len="300"/> </url -->
<t>
 <!-- Another comment -->
</t>
```

**the wanted comment node is selected and copied to the output:**

```
<!-- url path="/jsp/Admin_BetaSignup.jsp" roles="ZohoCampaignAdmin" authentication="optional" description="Page used to add the Beta users">         <param name="zuid" xss="throwerror" max-len="300"/> </url -->
```

Answer (score 3):

Comment isn't element node, it doesn't contain attributes. So you have to get all comment nodes, then parse them.